# Too many crosstab column headers error using MS Access crosstab query

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am trying to export an MS-Access crosstab query, but get the error message "Too many crosstab column headers".

[image: the error]

As it turns out, MS-Access has a limit to the number of columns a query can have (255 columns).

After some online searching, I did not encounter any viable solutions...
One solution is splitting up the query into multiple ones with less than 255 columns, but you would need to create multiple queries that depend on the number of columns, which could be unknown. It is not a really simple task to implement.

Is there any  way to export a crosstab query with more than 255 columns to an excel file? And more specifically: Is there any solution using VBA code?

Comment: Please post your crosstab SQL and Excel export code. You need to break apart the crosstab into multiple queries either with `WHERE` or crosstab's `IN()` clause.

Answer (score 4):

My proposed solution is using the query as a normal (non-crosstab) query, exporting it to an excel file, then creating a "Pivot Table" (same as crosstab) in the file. This can be done manually, But I wanted to make it an automatic process using code.

I have written this VBA sub, which outputs a given MS-Access query to an excel file and manipulates it to a pivot table (with more than 255 columns!):

```
Sub export_query_to_pivot(query_name As String, folder_name As String, file_name As String)

    ' Outputs the query to an excel file in the chosen path, and creates a pivot table
    If folder_name <> "" Then

        MsgBox "Exporting begins! Do not open the file until a message appears"

        ' Output the query to excel file
        DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, query_name, acFormatXLSX, folder_name & file_name

        ' --------- Manipulate the excel file to create a pivot table using code
        ' Using a mechanism called "Late-Binding" to handle the excel file (notice we define it as an "Object", and then set the object type)
        Dim excel_object As Object
        Dim work_book As Object
        Dim src_sheet As Object
        Dim pivot_sheet As Object
        Dim last_row As Long
        Dim last_column As Long

        Set excel_object = CreateObject("Excel.Application") ' Instantiate the Excel instance
        Set work_book = excel_object.Workbooks.Open(folder_name & file_name) ' Open the workbook
        Set src_sheet = work_book.Sheets(1) ' Set the source sheet (the outputted query data)
        Set pivot_sheet = work_book.Sheets.Add ' Create a new sheet for the pivot table

        last_row = src_sheet.Range("A" & src_sheet.Rows.Count).End(-4162).row ' Get the index of the last row
        last_column = src_sheet.Range("A1").End(-4161).Column ' Get the index of the last column

        src_sheet.Name = "Source_Sheet" ' Change the name of the source sheet to..... "Source_Sheet"!
        pivot_sheet.Name = "Pivot_Sheet" ' ...You get the idea

        ' -------- Create the pivot table -------- '
        work_book.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=1, SourceData:="Source_Sheet!R1C1:R" & CStr(last_row) & "C" & CStr(last_column), Version:=1) _
            .CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Pivot_Sheet!R1C1", _
            TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=1

        src_sheet.Select
        src_sheet.Cells(3, 1).Select

        ' -------- Set the pivot table rows, column, and value: -------- '
        ' The last column of the query is the field for the Pivot Value & Column

        Dim i As Integer
        Dim field_name As String
        For i = 1 To last_column

            field_name = src_sheet.Cells(1, i).Value ' Get the field name

            If i <> last_column Then
                ' Set the row fields
                With pivot_sheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields(field_name)
                    .Orientation = 1 ' 1 = xlRowField constant in early binding
                    .Position = i
                End With
            Else ' Last column
                ' Create the value field
                pivot_sheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField pivot_sheet.PivotTables( _
                    "PivotTable1").PivotFields("Full_Name"), "Count of " & field_name, -4112 ' -4112 = xlCount constant
                ' Create the column field
                With pivot_sheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields(field_name)
                    .Orientation = 2 ' 2 = xlColumnField constant in early binding
                    .Position = 1
                End With
            End If

            ' Turn off all subtotals:
            pivot_sheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields(field_name).Subtotals _
            = Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)

        Next i

        ' -------- Change the pivot table properties --------'

        ' Turn sheet from left to right
        pivot_sheet.DisplayRightToLeft = False
        ' Turn off row grand totals
        pivot_sheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").RowGrand = False
        ' Turn on label repeat
        pivot_sheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").RepeatAllLabels 2 ' 2 = xlRepeatLabels in early binding
        ' Show in Tabular Form
        pivot_sheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").RowAxisLayout 1 ' 1= xlTabularRow in early binding
        ' Put 0 in empty cells
        pivot_sheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").NullString = "0"

        pivot_sheet.Select

        ' -------- Save & Close the workbook -------- '
        work_book.Save
        work_book.Close
        Set work_book = Nothing
        Set excel_object = Nothing
        Set src_sheet = Nothing
        Set pivot_sheet = Nothing

        MsgBox "Done Exporting!"
    End If
End Sub
```

This code uses the last column of the input query as the Value & Column heading of the pivot table, and the rest of the columns as the Row headings.

As you can see, some lines in the code set the Pivot Table's properties. you can change those lines & add new ones. 
You can read more about the [PivotTable object here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837611.aspx).

Usage example:

```
Dim query_name As String
Dim folder_name As String
Dim file_name As String

query_name = "rare_cats_query"
file_name = "Rare_Cats_Pivot.xlsx"
folder_name = "C:\Users\Drump\Desktop\"

' Create the pivot table using the function "export_query_to_pivot"
export_query_to_pivot query_name, folder_name, file_name
```

We export the query "rare_cats_query" to an excel file named "Rare_Cats_Pivot.xlsx" to the user's desktop. A pivot table is created in a new spreadsheet.